# Page crashed error coming when using react-snap

Tags: reactjs, react-snap

So react-snap automatically runs after npm run build which is defined in postbuild command ,
Sorry i had to comment my computer paths due to company policy

```
xxxxxxxxxx@0.1.0 postbuild /home/xxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx
> react-snap
️  console.log at /: [GPT] Invalid arguments: PubAdsService.refresh().
️  console.log at /: [GPT] Invalid arguments: PubAdsService.refresh().
️  console.log at /: [GPT] Invalid arguments: PubAdsService.refresh().
️  console.log at /: [GPT] Invalid arguments: PubAdsService.refresh().
️  console.log at /: [GPT] Invalid arguments: PubAdsService.refresh().
️  console.log at /: [GPT] Invalid arguments: PubAdsService.refresh().
  error at /: Error: Page crashed!
    at Page._onTargetCrashed (/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:215:24)
    at CDPSession.Page.client.on.event (/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:123:56)
    at CDPSession.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at CDPSession._onMessage (/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:200:12)
    at Connection._onMessage (/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:112:17)
    at WebSocketTransport._ws.addEventListener.event (/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/WebSocketTransport.js:44:24)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:198:13)
```

Comment: Please provide more details